# XMLRPC catching script execution errors and displaying them in the response

Tags: php, error-handling, xml-rpc

How can I pass script execution errors to the XMLRPC response so I don't get a Fault Exception?

Maybe I'm not setting this up right:

In the XMLRPC server I'm adding `Zend_XmlRpc_Server_Fault::attachFaultException('Exception');` like this:

```
Zend_XmlRpc_Server_Fault::attachFaultException('Exception');
$server = new Zend_XmlRpc_Server();
```

But I still get a Fault Exception:

```
Fault Exception:\n651Failed to parse response
```

How can I pass the script execution errors to the response?

I've also tried to set this with no luck:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors",1);
ini_set("xmlrpc_errors",1);
```

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Example XMLRPC error when script has errors:

```
Fault Exception:\n651Failed to parse response
```

Example of when script has errors:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method
```

Both are from the same script error, but I need the XMLRPC to display the Fatal error message in the response instead of giving the failed to parse response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [set_error_handler()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function to intercept a script error and instead throw an [ErrorException](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php):

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
```

So when you call Zend_XmlRpc_Server::handle():

```
set_error_handler('exception_error_handler');
$server->handle();
restore_error_handler();
```

**Edit:** Example #1 from the ErrorException page is wrong. Use the version in this answer instead.

Comment: Hmm, this give me a 404 faultCode and a unknown error faultString when adding the code: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [faultCode] => 404
            [faultString] => Unknown error
        )

)

Comment: if I remove your code the functionality works just fine, adding your code I get the above comment

Comment: My bad, the code was wrong. I copy/pasted a bad example from php.net. Also, I see you specifically wanted to trap a _fatal_ error. These can't be trapped at all, you must stop them before they happen. Where is your fatal error occurring?

Comment: I just want this for development as running the XMLRPC with new functionality sometimes breaks the current process. Right now I have a separate script the just instantiates a new class and runs through the same process as the XMLRPC service would. Correct the errors (if any) and then run the XMLRPC service to finalize the process. Every once in a while something might slip past the testing causing the XMLRPC to give the Fault Exception:\n651Failed to parse response which is a pain to track down sometimes. just looking for a more effective way to debug/test

Comment: one other note is I echo/print the XMLRPC response (which is an array during development) of all the actions performed, echo $server->handle(); in Production I just give the last action performed as the XMLRPC response